# UWP PWA: Subdomain as start page

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to publish my PWA as a UWP app but I have trouble with the subdomain, it's hosted on.

E.g. when I set https://example.com/ as StartPage it perfectly works but when using https://sub.example.com/ it keeps showing the startup screen (app logo).

Both domains contain almost the same source code and in MS Edge, both work.

Package.appxmanifest:

```
<Application Id="App" StartPage="https://sub.example.com/">
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you include the subdomain URL in the **Content URIs** tab in the `Package.appxmanifest` editor:

[image: URL in Content URIs]

Alternatively, include it in the XML code in the `uap:ApplicationCntentUriRules` element:

```
<uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
  <uap:Rule Match="https://blog.mzikmund.com" Type="include" 
            WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
  <uap:Rule Match="https://*.*" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="none" />
  <uap:Rule Match="http://*.*" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="none" />
</uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
```